# jquery - on submit form before form is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#step1_next").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.post('step2.php', $("#step1_next").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#step2_div').html(data);


            $("#step2_form").on("submit", function() {

                $.post('../model/step2.php', $("#step2_form").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#step2_controller').html(data);
                });

                return false;

            });


        });
    }
});
});
```

Basically, what I wanted to do is that when step2.php is rendered, another ajax function is attached onto step2_form (inside step2.php).

This code doesn't work probably because "step2_form" isn't loaded yet. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#step1_next").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post('step2.php', $("#step1_next").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#step2_div').html(data);


                $(document).on("submit", "#step2_form", function() {

                    $.post('../model/step2.php', $("#step2_form").serialize(), function(data) {
                        $('#step2_controller').html(data);
                    });

                    return false;

                });


            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Istead of `$("#step2_form").serialize()`, we can also do `$(this).serialize()`